# What consistency guarantees does Firebase make (specifically REST api)?

Tags: firebase

Let's say:

- I make a PUT request to add a child at `/parent/child1`, and when it returns I GET `/parent`
- From a different server on the other side of the world but at just about the same time, I start a PUT request to add a child at `/parent/child2` and when it returns I GET `/parent`

If I don't make any other requests to these locations, is the response of at least one of the GET requests guaranteed to contain both `child1` and `child2`?

And, of course, if I do this 50 times for `child1` through `child50` all at once, am I guaranteed that at least one of these GET requests will contain all fifty children?

Answer (score 1):

After a write operation completes, the next read operation will see the result of that write. Since you only start the GET after the PUT has completed, the last one will indeed see all previously written children.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any docs to support this? It's tricky - for example, it could be the _first_ GET that sees all the children, depending on things.

Comment: That indeed could be. Firebase is ideally used for state synchronization scenarios. When you use one of the Firebase SDKs or the REST Streaming API, then every client will eventually have the exact same state (https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-03-24-streaming-for-firebase-rest-api.html).